# Can i route host directly to a path in the backend?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress

I am using nginx-ingress.

Is it possible to route host to a path of the backend?

For example,

foo.example.com/ -> my-service:80/myapp/gui/
bar.example.com/ -> my-service:80/different/path/here

I tried this

```
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              name: http
            path: /myapp/gui/
```

Thought, it's throwing an error with unknown field.

`$ k apply -f ingress.yaml  error: error validating "ingress.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.service): unknown field "path" in io.k8s.api.networking.v1.IngressServiceBackend; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's can be done with two ingress config class and use of`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation to route change the path :

```yaml
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /myapp/gui/$2
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: foo.example.com
        http:
          paths:
            - path: (/|$)(.*)
              backend:
                serviceName: my-service
                servicePort: 80
```

```yaml
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /different/path/here/$2
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: bar.example.com
        http:
          paths:
            - path: (/|$)(.*)
              backend:
                serviceName: my-service
                servicePort: 80
```

The path will be `"/myapp/gui/$2"` where `$2` will be replaced by your subpath.

```
foo.example.com/ -> my-service:80/myapp/gui/ 
foo.example.com/test -> my-service:80/myapp/gui/test
bar.example.com/ -> my-service:80/different/path/here
bar.example.com/test -> my-service:80/different/path/here/test
```

Comment: This what actually what i have found and works as intended. Thank you for your help!